# Dockerfile failed because of E: Version x for y was not found

Tags: docker, bioinformatics, apt-get, dockerfile

I wrote the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

MAINTAINER X

# Setup OS
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get -y install python-software-properties
RUN apt-get -y install software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:nebc/bio-linux
RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y wget

RUN apt-get install -y python-setuptools python-docutils python-pip
#RUN pip install snakemake

RUN apt-get install -y emboss=6.6.0+dfsg-2biolinux1
RUN apt-get install -y hmmer=3.1b1-0biolinux1 
RUN apt-get install -y lastz=1.02.00-3biolinux1.1 
RUN apt-get install -y ncbi-blast+=2.2.28-3ubuntu1
```

Unfortunately, I have got the following errors, but the packages are listed [here](https://launchpad.net/%7Enebc/+archive/ubuntu/bio-linux/+index?batch=75&memo=75&start=75)

```
E: Version '3.1b1-0biolinux1' for 'hmmer' was not found
E: Version '2.2.28-3ubuntu1' for 'ncbi-blast+' was not found
```

How can install the above packages with a specific version?

Comment: I see that the version available with ubuntu 14.04 is  `apt-cache show hmmer
Package: hmmer
Priority: extra
Section: universe/science
Installed-Size: 10672
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian Med Packaging Team <debian-med-packaging@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 3.1b1-3` but the build still fails with `RUN apt-get install -y hmmer=3.1b1-3biolinux1`